# Bind rows of data frames with some factor columns

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, tidyverse

I want to create a suped-up version of `dplyr::bind_rows` that avoids the `Unequal factor levels: coercing to character` warnings when factor columns are present in the dfs we're trying to combine (which may also have non-factor columns). Here's an example:

```
df1 <- dplyr::data_frame(age = 1:3, gender = factor(c("male", "female", "female")), district = factor(c("north", "south", "west")))
df2 <- dplyr::data_frame(age = 4:6, gender = factor(c("male", "neutral", "neutral")), district = factor(c("central", "north", "east")))
```

then `bind_rows_with_factor_columns(df1, df2)` returns (without warnings):

```
dplyr::data_frame(
  age = 1:6,
  gender = factor(c("male", "female", "female", "male", "neutral", "neutral")),
  district = factor(c("north", "south", "west", "central", "north", "east"))
)
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
bind_rows_with_factor_columns <- function(...) {
  factor_columns <- purrr::map(..., function(df) {
      colnames(dplyr::select_if(df, is.factor))
  })

  if (length(unique(factor_columns)) > 1) {
      stop("All factor columns in dfs must have the same column names")
  }

  df_list <- purrr::map(..., function (df) {
    purrr::map_if(df, is.factor, as.character) %>% dplyr::as_data_frame()
  })

  dplyr::bind_rows(df_list) %>%
    purrr::map_at(factor_columns[[1]], as.factor) %>%
    dplyr::as_data_frame()
}
```

I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to incorporate the `forcats` package to potentially avoid having to coerce factors to characters, or if anyone has any suggestions in general to boost the performance of this while maintaining the same functionality (I'd like to stick to `tidyverse` syntax). Thanks!

Comment: Why not just `do.call(rbind, list(df1, df2))`?

Comment: `suppressWarnings` or `purrr::quietly`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to answer my own question based on a great solution from a friend:

```
bind_rows_with_factor_columns <- function(...) {
  purrr::pmap_df(list(...), function(...) {
    cols_to_bind <- list(...)
    if (all(purrr::map_lgl(cols_to_bind, is.factor))) {
      forcats::fct_c(cols_to_bind)
    } else {
      unlist(cols_to_bind)
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be simpler, to use `dplyr::bind_rows` with warnings suppressed, and then convert all the new character columns back to factors. This has the advantage of binding `data.frames` by column names (allowing for different ordering of columns and inclusion of extra columns), and still works when factor variables are sometimes recorded as characters.

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows_keep_factors <- function(...) {
  ## Identify all factors
  factors <- unique(unlist(
    map(list(...), ~ select_if(..., is.factor) %>% names())
  ))
  ## Bind dataframes, convert characters back to factors
  suppressWarnings(bind_rows(...)) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(one_of(factors)), factor)  
}

dat1 <- tibble(
  id = 1:2,
  fruit = factor(c("banana", "apple"))
)

dat2 <- tibble(
  id = 3:4,
  fruit = c("pear", "banana"),
  taste = c("Mmmm", "yum")
)

bind_rows_keep_factors(dat1, dat2)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
     id fruit  taste
  <int> <fct>  <chr>
1     1 banana NA   
2     2 apple  NA   
3     3 pear   Mmmm 
4     4 banana yum
```

Of course, the ordering of factor levels are disrupted (revert to alphabetical).